# Error running npm install, returns This is a bug in `node-gyp`

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, neo4j

I am new to Angular and Node. I am trying to execute an project created using Angular, Neo4j.
At first, I tried to run it as it is. However, i am givem the following error after opening the browser:

> NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterScroller -> >ViewportScroller]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterScroller -> ViewportScroller]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewportScroller!
>
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Neo4jError: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3
> Neo4jError: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3

Then, I tried an clean install following this process:

1. Delete the node_modules from project;
2. Run `npm install --global windows-build-tools`
3. Run `npm install`

Then i am given this error:

> ```
> gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
> gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
> gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
> gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
> gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\PROJECT\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\USER_NAME\PROJECT\node_modules\node-sass
> gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
> gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
> gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
> gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
> ```

Sorry for the wall of text. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

---

**Edit:**

I've also tried the following:

1. Rebuilding the `node-gyp` bindings by running `node-gyp rebuild`, however that returns the following error:

   > ```
   > binding.gyp not found while trying to load binding.gyp
   > gyp ERR! configure error
   > gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
   > gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
   > ```
2. I can confirm that `node-gyp` is installed globally because I ran: `npm install -g node-gyp`
3. I tried the gyp rebuild using python 2.7.18 to no avail. Still returning the same error.

**Edit 2:**

I no longer have access to the project. So I cannot test any new solutions pointed.

Regardless, Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: This is happening due to python version, install x-code and reinstall all node packages again.

Comment: Are you running it inside of vscode or something? If so try from a command line tool like cmder

Comment: @DanielJeney yes it was on vscode. Unfortunaly, I am no longer part of the project and no longer have access to the files. But, thank you for your sugestion, i will keep it in mind for a next time

Answer (score 0):

This is a known canvas issue, probably caused by missing native libs.
Try this see if it helps:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g node-gyp
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
brew install pkg-config cairo libpng jpeg giflib
npm i canvas
```

Comment: the question referred to windows (as in windows-build-tools), not MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was solved by using Node Version 14

tested with docker first `docker pull node:14.10.0`